# Expo ENOENT open '192.168.0.104:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false'

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, expo

Expo gives me this error only when i try to run the app on my phone. I quadriplechecked if i'm logging raw response in console as it was suggested in the other thread, but i don't, for sure. What else can be the cause?

```
 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ira/dev/eshka/http:/192.168.0.104:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
    at getCodeFrame (/home/ira/dev/eshka/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:949:18)
    at Server._symbolicate (/home/ira/dev/eshka/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1022:22)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at Server._processRequest (/home/ira/dev/eshka/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:429:7) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/home/ira/dev/eshka/http:/192.168.0.104:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false'
}
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ira/dev/eshka/http:/192.168.0.104:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
    at getCodeFrame (/home/ira/dev/eshka/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:949:18)
    at Server._symbolicate (/home/ira/dev/eshka/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1022:22)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at Server._processRequest (/home/ira/dev/eshka/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:429:7) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/home/ira/dev/eshka/http:/192.168.0.104:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false'
}
```